# Create a new trace id everytime a scheduled runnable task is invoked

Tags: runnable, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In my code I have scheduled a runnable task using the schedule method of task schedular. I went through this link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-runnablecallable-integration. I implemented this way. The current state is - for any schedule a trace is created, and the same trace id is being used for all the runs invoked by this schedule, though spans are new. But I want that each run should have it's own unique trace id. There is a method of tracer which creates a new trace, but is there any way to do this in sleuth by which I can avoid manual creation of a new trace? I am using the 2.0.x version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I created a new trace using newtrace method of tracer which returns a span.
2. Started this span.
3. Then added this span in the currentscope using withspaninscope method.
4. Started scoped span for the runnable task and finished both of these spans.

It worked.